# Can't change the permissions in destination server while doing sFTP

Tags: linux, permissions, sftp

From server A to server B copying files via SFTP. Files copied with permissions of 700, If i change the permissions of the file in server B ,sftp is not working as its says" permissions Denied". But i want to give permissions for other users.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using the manual; man sftp or reading the output of sftp --help would provide you with the option -P (UNIX) or -p (Linux) which coupled with the servers sftp-subsystem umask option will ensure your permissions are what you will expect

Comment: Using option P , not working. :-(

Comment: It is -P for UNIX and -p in Linux. The target systems umask for the sftp-subshell and defaults per account also apply.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear whether the permissions are correct on the source copy, and you want the destination to inherit those permissions, or whether you want to set the permissions explicitly on the target

To copy permissions along with the file, the man page clearly shows:

> put -p local-path [remote-path]
>
> If either the `-p` flag is specified, then full file permissions and access times are copied too

If you want to set permissions explicitly, the man page also offers:

> `chmod mode path` Change permissions of file path to `mode`. `path` may contain [glob(3)](https://linux.die.net/man/3/glob) characters and may match multiple files.

Comment: Hi, wanted to change permission in target, i can use CHMOD to change , after i change the permissions in taget, next time sftp not working as its says "permissions denied".

Comment: @ram to what are you changing the permissions?